# how can dynamically verify and execute a method?

Tags: ruby, workflow, state-machine

Using workflow is amazing! it defines states and new methods as "can_submit?" and so "submit!"

there is a way to verify an action and so execute it?

```
def do(name)
    canDoIt = eval "self.can_" + name + "?" 
    canDoIt ? eval "self." + name + "!" : "Sorry...cant do that action..."
end
```

how could be done?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question...
Is this what you want?

```
def do(name)
  if respond_to?("#{name}!") && send("can_#{name}?")
    send("#{name}!")
  else
    'Sorry...cant do that action...'
  end
end
```